# Is it possible to listen to a method call in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, reflection

Given an instance of MyClass, I want to be notified when someone calls an specific method.

example:

```
package bar;
{
  public class MyClass {

      private var foo:int;

      public function MyClass() { foo = 2; }
      public function getFoo():int { return foo; }
  }
}
```

So given a instance of MyClass ( `var instance = new MyClass()` ) i want to be notified every time getFoo is called. I have tried using reflection+annotations+dynamic classes, to find that in AS3 you can't change seal methods (methods defined in the class). I was wondering if i can subscript to a event in order to be notified when the method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event for every method call, and MyClass is not even EventDispatcher. I suppose you cannot alter MyClass definition, otherwise that would be too simple.

Comment: BTW, lame language AS3. =( persisting is so hard

Answer (score 0):

you could create your own custom event class and dispatch your custom events from those methods when they are returned.

**edit:**  oh, i just realized you're trying to get event notifications from a final class.  in which case you can't dispatch your own custom events.